# Find First File always returns INVALID_HANDLE_TRUE

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing a C++ console application to list all of the files in a given directory. My code is as follows, but it always returns "INVALID_HANDLE_TRUE". I've used windows.h library and used WIN 32 FIND DATA  and FindFirstFile function to open up a directory

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int getDirectory(const char *directory, vector<string> &files)
{
    string storage;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)directory, &fd);
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    { 
        cout << "Invalid handle for: " << directory; 
        return 0; 
    }

    while(1){
        cout << (fd.cFileName) ;
        if (FindNextFile(h, &fd) == FALSE) 
        { 
            break; 
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    vector <string> files;
    char *directory;
    cout << "Directory: ";
    // cin >> directory;

    directory ="c:\\*.*";
    cout << directory << endl;
    getDirectory(directory, files);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i< files.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << files[i] << endl;
    }

    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: casting const char* to LPCWSTR seems wrong?

Comment: if I remove that, it gives an error

Comment: that doesn't make it right.. Try `FindFirstFileA` for the ANSI version, or use wchar

Comment: You're casting a `char` to a `wide char`.

Comment: @Yagiz the error is the clue.

Comment: Why bother passing `directory` at all? You can always write `(LPCWSTR)NULL` and the compiler will accept it! Casting a variable to a type does not actually make that variable be the right type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `directory` variable is of type `const char *`. I suspect that you are building with `UNICODE` being defined for the preprocessor though, which means that `FindFirstFile` is actually `FindFirstFileW` - i.e. it expects a `const wchar_t *`.

Try changing `FindFirstFile` to `FindFirstFileA`, explicitely requesting the ANSI variant of the function which takes a `const char *` as its first argument, and you no longer need the incorrect cast.

Comment: After that, my WIN32_FIND_DATA gives an error in the line h =FindFirstFileA(directory, &fd) with '&' underlined.

Comment: error C2664: findfirstfilea cannot convert parameter 2 from 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA*' to 'LPWIN32_FIN_DATAA' (one is with the star)

Comment: The only way you can get that kind of error is if you changed your variable from `WIN32_FIND_DATA` to `LPWIN32_FIND_DATA`. Like `FindFirstFile()`, `WIN32_FIND_DATA` also has Ansi and Unicode variables. Your declaration needs to be `WIN32_FIND_DATAA fd;`, then pass it to `FindFirstFileA()` using `&fd`.